# how to pipe exceljs stream to reply in hapijs

Tags: stream, streaming, hapi.js, exceljs

I'm using exceljs to generate an excel file(using its streaming capabilities). Instead of saving the file on the server and then reading and returning it, I want to directly stream the exceljs stream to the response in hapijs.

```
function(request, reply) {
  const options = {
    stream: reply, // I need to somehow declare the reply stream here
    useStyles: false,
    useSharedStrings: true
  };

  const workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(options);
  workbook.addWorksheet('Test');
  const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Test');

  worksheet.columns = [{
    header: 'product', key: 'product'
  }];

  worksheet.addRow({product: 'MyProduct'}).commit();
  worksheet.commit();
  workbook.commit();
```

Is this possible? I cannot directly pass reply to the options of the Exceljs stream as I would do in expressjs? Any thoughts?

Comment: Reply can return a stream but I would wrap exceljs logic in your own streaming interface which you can pass to hapi's reply interface, I used the module **[j](https://www.npmjs.com/package/j)** to achieve this.  Look at [this](https://github.com/circabs/xl-json) module to show how you can wrap a stream, in my example it was converting from excel to json

Answer (score 1):

```
var wb = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter();
var sh = wb.addWorksheet('sheet1');
sh.columns = [
    { header: 'Name', key: 'name' },
    { header: 'Age', key: 'age' }
];

sh.addRow(['Ben', 8]);
sh.addRow(['Dave', 10]);

sh.commit();
wb.commit()
.then(function () {
    var stream = wb.stream;
    var b = stream.read();

    reply(b)
    .type('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    .header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=file.xlsx')
    .header('Content-Length', stream.length);
});
```

Comment: Code only and "try this" answers are discouraged. Please explain why and how this solves op's problem.

Comment: You can read the Streaming XLSX section at the exceljs library site,  it explains over there about the usage

Comment: Sorry if my previous comment came across rude. Though you still may want to include extra information to improve the long-term value of your answer. "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline" - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs/blob/master/README.md#streaming-xlsx - it explains there, although there are no given examples

Comment: The important notes are : "If neither stream nor filename is specified in the options, the workbook writer will create a StreamBuf object that will store the contents of the XLSX workbook in memory. This StreamBuf object, which can be accessed via the property workbook.stream, can be used to either access the bytes directly by stream.read() or to pipe the contents to another stream."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.